# Close icon on dynamic div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a `div` which I create dynamically. I also switch the div's visibility using `display:none` and `display:block`. I want to create a close icon for that div using plain **Javascript** and **CSS**. Is that possible?

I have tried using an simple X icon for changing the visibility.

Here is my **CSS**:

```
.dhSeriesToolbar {
     max-height: 200px;
     width:400px;
     background-color: black;
     z-index:999;
     display:none;
     overflow:auto;
     border: 2px solid #33ccff;
     padding-left: 15px;
     padding-top: 15px;
     padding-bottom: 15px;
     position:absolute;
 }
```

Comment: yes, that's possible. Could you copy your current code ?

Comment: What is your JS code? Which creates a div. You can't create close icon with only CSS (JS is needed to hide/show a div when icon is clicked and css to set a corresponding style)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to see your code to help you better. But the idea is the following: add an icon (`<img>`) in your `<div>` element, and bind a Javascript call to the *onclick* event that will hide (or remove, regarding your needs) the `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

yes possible...do like this

```
// javascript part
myfunction(){
document.getElementById("divShowHide").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
}

// html part
<img src="icon.png" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also play with `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a close icon too dynamically along with that `div` e-g

```
$("body").append("<div class='dynamically_created_div'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='closeDiv()'></a></div>");

function closeDiv() {
  $(".dynamically_created_div").hide();
}
```